# How to call function from Rust naked function?

Tags: rust

just started learning Rust. How do you manage a function call from a Rust naked function? Normally,

```
pub extern "C" fn bar() {
    hprintln!("Function Call!");
}

pub extern "C" fn foo() {
    unsafe {
        asm!(
            "blx {}",
            ...
            in(reg) bar as u32,
        );
    }
}
```

But `foo()` being a naked call, I cannot use a register to pass values. There aren't much documentation on this feature and only thing I figured is that I can use `constant` and `symbol`, but I'm not sure how they are used. Any useful documentation on this feature or usage guideline would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What is a naked call?

Comment: I don't think this is a question about Rust at all. This seems to be a question about the C ABI. You're using `extern "C"`, which means [this function uses the ABI from C](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#using-extern-functions-to-call-external-code). If you want to manually write assembly to call that function, you'll need to work out how to do that for C, the fact that the function body is from Rust is irrelevant.

Comment: By "C ABI", Rust means ["whatever default your C compiler supports"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/external-blocks.html#abi), there are more specific platform-dependent options if you want. You definitely need to use one of them though, because the Rust ABI is not stable and cannot be relied upon.

Answer (score -3):

Figured out a quick fix: function parameters are stored in registers (r0-r3).

```
pub extern "C" fn bar() {
    hprintln!("Function Call!");
}

#[naked]
pub extern "C" fn foo(ft: u32) {
    unsafe {
        asm!(
            "blx r0", // ft is stored in r0
        );
    }
}

// somewhere
foo(bar as u32);
```

I believe there are different ways to solve this using `constant` and `symbol` though. Would appreciate any input.